# C# Programming: Maintaining a List that Associates an ID with Information Quickly

Tags: c#, database, database-design

In a game that I've been working on, I created a system by which the game polls a specific 'ItemDatabase' file in order to retrieve information about itself based on a given identification number.  The identification number represented the point in the database at which the information regarding a specific item was stored.  The representation of every item in the database was comprised of 162 bytes.  The code for the system was similar to the following:

```
// Retrieves the information about an 'Item' object given the ID.  The 
// 'BinaryReader' object contains a file stream to the 'ItemDatabase' file.
public Item(ushort ID, BinaryReader itemReader)
{
    // Since each 'Item' object is represented by 162 bytes of information in the 
    // database, skip 162 bytes per ID skipped.
    itemReader.BaseStream.Seek(162 * ID, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    // Retrieve the name of this 'Item' from the database.
    this.itemName = itemReader.ReadChars(20).ToString();
}
```

Normally there wouldn't be anything particularly wrong with this system as it queries the desired data and initializes it to the correct variables.  However, this process must occur during game time, and, based on research that I've done about the efficiency of the 'Seek' method, this technique won't be nearly fast enough to be incorporated into a game.  So, my question is: What's a good way to maintain a list that associates an identification number with information that can be accessed quickly?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't load the entire file into an array in memory?  The OS will take care of paging memory to disk if it really needs to.  Once it's in an array, it's fast and easy to work with each Item.

Comment: As game development continues, there could be a very large list of items.  If, say, the list reached 3000 or so unique items, would it be taxing to memory?  i just want to make sure I don't load to much to RAM while still having the item loading process as speedy as possible.

Comment: On a modern PC, 3,000 items at 162 bytes each is nothing.  That's only 486,000 bytes.  You might have had trouble in the olden days, when you had a memory space that had to be significantly less than 640K, but you're using C# and managed code (and the runtime is taking up a lot more than 640K).  You don't really need to start worrying until you get into the hundreds of MB.

Comment: So, if I completely fill up the item list (162 bytes per item at a maximum of 65536 items, so about 10 MB), I'll still be in the clear?  Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You best shot would be a database. [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is very portable and does not need to be installed on the system.

If you have loaded all the data into memory, you can use `Dictionary<int, Item>`. This makes it very easy to add and remove items to the list.

As it seems like your IDs all go from 0 and upwards, it would be really fast with just an array. Just set the index of the item to be the id.

Comment: If ID is continuous (as it appears to be from the example code), an array is much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the information in the "database" is not being changed continuously, couldn't you just read out the various items once-off during the load of the game or level?  You could store the data in a variety of ways, such as a Dictionary.  The .Net Dictionary is actually what is commonly referred to as a hash table, mapping keys (in this case, your ID field) to objects (which I am guessing is of type "Item").  Lookup times are extremely good (definitely in the millions per second), I doubt you'd ever have issues.

Alternatively, if your ID is a ushort, you could just store your objects in an array with all possible ushort values.  An array of 65535 length is not large in today's terms.  Array lookups are as fast as you can get.

Comment: The absolute maximum number of items would be 65536 items (which I doubt I would ever reach, but I'd like to have more room than is given with a byte).  So, if I loaded an array with 65536 items, it wouldn't be too much of a burden on memory resources?

Comment: Well, you said each item is 162 bytes, so 162 * 65536 = 10616832 bytes.  That's just over 10 megabytes, which is not much in today's terms, unless you are coding for mobiles or other such devices.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) or if this is used in a multi-threaded app then [`ConcurrentDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) .

Extremely fast but a bit more effort in implementing is a [`MemoryMappedFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx) .